# Can't seem to bake fire animation?

Tags: animation, physics, fire

I am new to baking and animation in general, but I was in the process of trying to add a basic fire/smoke animation in Blender 2.82. In the process, I create my smoke domain (using quick smoke) and fiddle with Cache Type until I can actually get the render to display.

Once I run it through the replay, I switch type to final, bake it, and it seems to be working - YAY! I then go to my other object and follow the same workflow, yet when I bake this one my original animation seems to just disappear? There is nothing that happens, the domain just becomes completely empty.

I thought maybe this is just a short-termed cache and once I bake the other animation it deleted the original, so I tried baking through object > animation > bake action, and this seemed to do the same thing.

What can I do to get this working? This seemed really interesting and fun, but now I can't seem to get it to work at all.

Comment: can you please add an image

Comment: I think I managed to solve it!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by saving each bake to a separate directory! This kept all of them for the final render.